# Create from SQL Database

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am following this step by step:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/getting-started-with-mvc/getting-started-with-mvc-part6

My question is when adding a create page, where does this come from? db.AddToMovies(newMovie) - It gives a build error on it (Contoller code below)?

Is this the best way to list, create and edit to a SQL table from Visual Studio 2019?

Thanks,
EB

I have added that already on the controller page. Is that a SP or something in the database?  db.AddToEmployees(newEmployee); is giving the issue. 
Here is the code not as I am trying to customize it:

```
                    IntranetEntities db = new IntranetEntities();
                    public ActionResult Employees()
                    {
                        var employees = from m in db.Employees
                                        select m;

                        return View(employees.ToList());

                    }


                    // GET: Employees/Details/5
                    public ActionResult Details(int id)
                    {
                        return View();
                    }

                    // GET: Employees/Create
                    public ActionResult Create()
                    {
                        return View();
                    }

                    // POST: Employees/Create
                    [HttpPost]

                    public ActionResult Create(Employee newEmployee)
                    {

                        if (ModelState.IsValid)
                        {
                            db.Employees(newEmployee);
                            db.SaveChanges();

                            return RedirectToAction("Employees");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return View(newEmployee);
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go previous page, it declare `MoviesEntities db = new MoviesEntities();`

```
public class MoviesController : Controller
    {
        MoviesEntities db = new MoviesEntities();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var movies = from m in db.Movies
                         where m.ReleaseDate > new DateTime(1984, 6, 1)
                         select m;

            return View(movies.ToList());

        }
    }
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/getting-started-with-mvc/getting-started-with-mvc-part5

Update:

`AddToMovies` may be a stored procedure in DB but I also could not find it in MSDN sample.

You can work around by change

```
db.AddToMovies(newMovie)
```

to

```
_db.Movies.Add(newMovie)
```

Comment: I have added that already on the controller page. Is that a SP or something in the database?

Here is the code not as I am trying to customize it: